# MOXy JAXB implementation not working for JAX-WS web services on Glassfish 4.0?

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, glassfish-4, moxy

I've been able to specify EclipseLink MOXy as my JAXB Provider as per Blaise Doughan's instructions here:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

I'm now trying to publish a web service, which incorporates some subclasses that include the `@XmlValue` annotation. (The JAXB reference implementation wont let you do this, but MOXy will). Anyway, I got the usual JAXB error message again:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: ...
@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.
```

...which means the web service is trying to use the reference implementation again, instead of MOXy.

I then found Blaise's blog post about how MOXy can be leveraged to create a JAX-WS service in GlassFish 3.1.2:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/glassfish-312-is-full-of-moxy.html

However, this doesn't work in Glassfish 4.0. I get the exception:

```
WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: 
com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: 
Unknown Databinding mode: eclipselink.jaxb
```

Indeed, Blaise himself has logged a bug report about this issue here:

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-1130

This seems to be unresolved still, so now I'm at a dead end. So my question is this: **Is there another way of getting MOXy to work with my JAX-WS web service using Glassfish 4.0 (or later)?**

Comment: I have the same problem using glassfish 4.1